# TortoiseGit: Rebase with conflict

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I think I'm doing something wrong but I'm not sure where. I have a working branch and a master branch. The working branch has some commits that aren't on the master branch yet. Now I have a critical bugfix that I commit to master. I also want to have this commit in the working branch, therefore I use rebase.

I open the rebase window in TortoiseGit and it shows this one commit. After clicking "Start Rebase" it informs me that several conflicts occured. I fix the conflicts and press "Commit" in the rebase window.

Now the commit shows up in the commit log. Good. But when I want to push it to the server I'm informed that HEAD is detached. I solve this with `git checkout -b temp` and push this temporary branch.

If I now fetch from origin and open the rebase window again, the commit I just pushed shows up again for rebase. I think it shouldn't show up there since it was already rebased.

I also checked when doing a commit without conflict, it doesn't show again in the rebase window.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Before opening the rebase dialog, what is the current(checkout) branch? Your working branch? or master branch?

Comment: are you working in a submodule repository?

Comment: When first rebase, did you Rebase "no branch"?

Comment: How do you perform the push? via command line "git push"? or using TortoiseGit to push?

Comment: when you fetch, do you mean that you perform the fetch in another repository?

Comment: why "open the rebase window again"? and what is the current branch?

Comment: @YueLinHo The checkout branch is the working branch. No, I'm not working in a submodule repo. No, I did not rebase "no branch". "No branch" is the result of the rebase. I used TortoiseGit push. No, fetch on the same repo just to be sure I have the current commit log. I openend the rebase window again because I was curious if the rebased commits show up or not.

Comment: The description seems to me too generic to give any advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the command line interface : after fixing a rebase conflict, you have to commit, and then tell git "proceed with the remaining actions of the current rebase" :

```
git rebase --continue
```

I don't know what TortoiseGit does or doesn't do, see if you have some action which could look like "continue rebase", or "resume rebase", or ...

---

Another thing about rebasing : `git` does not keep track of the commits which have already been rebased,
instead, it looks at the patch introduced by each commit to be rebased, and scans the target branch to see if a commit already applies the same patch.

When you have a conflict, you generally modify something in the resulting patch, so re-rebasing will not detect that the initial commit was actually applied, and that commit will re-appear.

One way to avoid this problem is to *merge* `master` into `branch`, instead of rebasing.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that the commit hashes change of rebased commits with conflicts. With different hashes git doesn't know that its the same commit.